# reconstructing a linear order corrupted by noise

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, posets, linear-orders

Suppose we have a partial order (efficiently computable), $\leq$, on $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\rho$ be the standard Euclidean metric.  We want to find a set $S^\prime = \{f(x): x \in S\}$ such that $S^\prime$ is a linear order under $\leq$ and the "error", $E = \sum_x {\rho(x,f(x))}$, is minimal over all such $S^\prime$ such that $S^\prime$ is linearly ordered.

Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

It's ok to relax "minimal" to "nearly minimal" or "good" (in some sense) and to vary $\rho$ or $E$ in reasonable ways.